# Why does $g$ have a global min at $x=0$ while $f$ does not and yet $g$ is defined in terms of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, limits, derivatives

> $1.$ Let $f(x) = x^2\sin(1/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0.$ Show that $0$ is a critical point of $f$ that is not a local maximum nor a local minimum nor an inflection point.
>
> $2.$ Let $g(x) = 2x^2+f(x).$ Show that $g$ does have a global minimum at $0,$ but $g'(x)$ changes sign infinitely often on both $(0,\epsilon)$ and $(-\epsilon,0)$ for any $\epsilon >0.$

Here's what I've done.

$1.$

By the product rule and chain rule, $f'(x) = 2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x).$ We will show that $f'(0)=0$ is undefined at $x=0,$ which will show that $f$ has a critical point at $x=0.$
$f'(0)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(h)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{h^2\sin(1/h)}{h}\\
=\lim\limits_{h\to0} h\sin(1/h)=\lim\limits.$

Since $-h\leq h\sin(1/h)\leq h\;\forall h\geq 0$ and $h\leq h\sin(1/h)\leq -h\;\forall h\leq 0,$ by the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim\limits_{h\to0}h\sin(1/h)=0=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}h=0.$ (by the Squeeze Theorem).

We first prove that $(0,0)$ is neither a local minimum nor a local maximum of $f.$ Notice that whenever $x$ is of the form $\dfrac{1}{-\frac\pi2+2n\pi},n\in\mathbb{Z},$ $\sin(1/x)=-1.$ We know this because $\sin(1/x)=-1$ whenever $1/x$ is of the form $-\frac\pi2+2n\pi,n\in\mathbb{Z}.$ As well, $\sin(1/x)=1$ whenever $x$ is of the form $\dfrac{1}{\frac\pi2+2n\pi},n\in\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow f(x)=x^2>0$ (as $x\neq 0$). Let $x_n = \dfrac{1}{-\frac\pi2+2n\pi},n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $y_n = \dfrac{1}{\frac\pi2+2n\pi},n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Note that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} -x_n^2=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(y_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n^2=0.$ Then $\forall \epsilon>0,$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N, |x_n|<\epsilon$ and $\exists N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N_2, |y_n|<\epsilon.$ Thus, when $N_3=\max\{N,N_2\},$ we have that $-\epsilon < x_n,y_n<\epsilon.$ So there exist $x_n,y_n \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\;\forall \epsilon >0$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x_n) = -x_n^2 < 0 <f(y_n) = y_n^2.$ A similar proof for $x<0$ can be shown by using the opposite values of $x_n$ and $y_n.$ Thus $f$ does not have a local maximum or minimum at $x=0.$

By the product rule and chain rule, $f''(x)=2\sin(1/x)-\dfrac{2}{x}\cos(1/x)-\dfrac{\sin(1/x)}{x^2}.$ When $x=\dfrac{1}{2n\pi},n\in\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\},f''(x)=-4n\pi.$ When $x=\dfrac{1}{-\frac\pi2+2n\pi},n\in\mathbb{Z},f''(x)=-2+(-\frac\pi2+2n\pi)^2>0.$ So, using a similar approach to above, with $x_n = \dfrac{1}{2n\pi}$ and $y_n=\dfrac{1}{-\frac\pi2+2n\pi},n\in\mathbb{N},$ we can show that $f$ does not have an inflection point when $x>0.$ The proof for $x<0$ also involves using negative values for $x_n$ and $y_n.$

$2.$

Since $f(0)=0, g(0)=2(0)^2+f(0)=0.$ We have that since $\sin(1/x)\geq -1\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}, g(x)=2x^2+x^2\sin(1/x)\geq x^2>0\;\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}.$ Hence $(0,0)$ is a global minimum for $g.$ Also, $g'(0)=0,$ so it is indeed a minimum. Here is the proof:
By the derivative definition, $$g'(0) =\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}\\
=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{2h^2+h^2\sin(1/h)}{h}.$$ From above, $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{h^2\sin(1/h)}{h}=0,$ and so since $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{2h^2}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}2h=0,g'(0)=0.$

Now, $g'(x) = 4x+2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x).$ We show that $g'(x)$ changes sign infinitely often on $(-\epsilon,0)$ and $(0,\epsilon)$ for any $\epsilon >0.$ We first show this result for $(0,\epsilon)$. Whenever $x=\dfrac{1}{n\pi},n\in\mathbb{N},g'(x)=\dfrac{4}{n\pi}+1>0.$ Whenever $x=\dfrac{1}{2n\pi},n\in\mathbb{N},g'(x)=\dfrac{2}{n\pi}-1<0.$ Let $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be the sequence defined by $y_n=\dfrac{1}{2n\pi}$ and let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be the sequence defined by $x_n=\dfrac{1}{n\pi}.$ We have that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n=0.$ So $\exists N_1\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N_1 \Rightarrow |x_n| < \epsilon, \forall \epsilon >0$ and $\exists N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N_2 \Rightarrow |y_n| < \epsilon, \forall \epsilon >0.$ Pick $N_4=\max\{N_1,N_2\}.$ So for all $n \geq N_4, 0< |y_n| = y_n <\epsilon$ and $0<|x_n|=x_n<\epsilon.$ Since $g'(y_n)<0$ at every $y_n$ and $g'(x_n)>0$ at every $x_n,$ we have that $g'(x)$ changes sign infinitely many times on $(0,\epsilon)$. The proof that $g'(x)$ changes sign inifinitely often on $(-\epsilon,0)$ is very similar. Notice that when $x=-\dfrac{1}{2n\pi},n\in\mathbb{N},g'(x)<0$ and when $x=-\dfrac{1}{n\pi},n\in\mathbb{N},n>1,g'(x)>0.$ We set $y_{n_2} =-\dfrac{1}{2n_2\pi}$ and $x_{n_2}=-\dfrac{1}{n_2\pi},n_2\in\mathbb{N}$ and obtain the same result as above.

> Edit: some notes: the work above can definitely be simplified. Also, I need to show that $f'(0)=0$ using the *definition* of a derivative and the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: At the very beginning. You havhen't shown that $f'(0) = 0$. The fact that the *derivative function* does not exist in $0$ does not imply non-existence of the derivative in $0$.

Comment: More generally, I think you're being a bit convoluted without hitting the main point of the question, which, I believe, emphasizes the fact that for $f$ differentiable in $[a,b]$,

 **1.** having $f'(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in [a,b]$ does not necessarily imply that the function has a local maximum/minimum or an inflection point in $x_0$,
 **2.** having a local mnimum in $x_0$ does not necessarily imply that $f'(x)>0$ ($f'(x)<0$) in any left (right) neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Sure: use the definition of derivative and Squeeze Theorem!

Comment: For question 1. there is no need to use second derivative. In fact showing that $f(x)$ changes sign infinitely many times in any neighborhood of $0$ shows already that $0$ is not a local max/min or an inflection point.

Comment: Yep, I was just talking about *q.1*- right now. So the steps are 1) show derivative is $0$ 2) show (as you've done) that $f(x)$ takes on *both* positive and negative values in *any* neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: correct! well done.

Comment: you can also get $g'(0)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For the function $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ for $x \ne 0\,$and $f(x)= 0$ if $x=0$, show that $f$ does not have local maximum or minimum in $0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510126/for-the-function-fx-x2-sin1-x-for-x-ne-0-and-fx-0-if-x-0-s)

Comment: Re the Q in the title only: No intrinsic paradox. E.g. $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ and $g(x)=1+(f(x))^6.$